# MVC Preserve carriage return - line feed in html

Tags: html

If have a field in my database with crlf's how do I preserve
that in HTML??

Is there a standard way of doing this??

Malcolm

EDIT: I am actually doing an MVC app if that hepls.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/struct/text.html#h-10.3.5

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the best way to do that is to replace the `\r\n` sequence with `<br />` tags, using whatever scripting language your database-backed website is in.

Other options include placing the text within a `<textarea>`. Or, if it is appropriate for your site, using akin to the `<pre>` tag (or the CSS attribute `white-space: pre`).

Comment: +1 for "white-space: pre".  Replacing CRLFs with <br />'s can get ugly, and moreso on a platform that automatically HtmlEncodes, like MVC.

Answer (score 4):

You can search/replace those characters with `<br />` to make the text output with breaklines. You could also use the `<pre>` tag to specify a particular piece of text's line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php, you can use [nl2br](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php). As stated in the documentation, nl2br inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string. It   Returns `string` with '<br />' or 
   '<br>' inserted before all newlines (*\r\n*,
   *\n\r*, *\n* and *\r*).