# Showing multiple lines of text through EL

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, el

I am having problem displaying a text with multiple lines. For example, the user can type their text in a `textarea` in a registration form and the text can be of more than one line i.e. he can hit the Enter (return) key to insert line breaks.

On one page, if I want to show the text that he typed and I use a textarea to display (with `EL`), it displays the way user had entered initially.

But on another page I need this text be shown in paragraph format (using `<p>` tag). On this page, when I display the value that the user entered while registering, it does not have the line breaks i.e. it displays in a single line rather than with multiple lines as was entered by the user.

I already tried displaying the text through `EL` within a `<p>` tag and using a `<c:out>` tag of the JSTL within a `<p>` tag.

**Some code that I tried:**
Trial-1:

```
<p>${product.description}</p> //Doesn't show line breaks
```

Trial-2:

```
<p><c:out value="${product.description}" /></p> //Doesn't show line breaks too
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you view the source sent to the browser ? Please try

```
<p><pre>${product.description}</pre></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now I can think of something as to replace the `\r\n` sequence in the `product.description` string with `<br />` with help of `scriptlets` or [`fn` JSTL (function) tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html)

Idea Courtesy: [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/764831/468763).